# What to do if "git push heroku master" failed?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a working Rails app on my local Windows XP machine. I want to upload it on Heroku. I follow this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3.

When I ran `git push heroku master`, it failed:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> WARNING: Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
Received disconnect from 50.19.85.132: 10: user closed connection
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What do I have to do now?

I saw the log, there are some issues like these ones:

```
2013-04-28T21:18:03.384881+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/assets/images/cards/resize.rb:23:in `open': No such file or directory -
 C:\sbox\ruby\cards2 (Errno::ENOENT)

2013-04-28T21:18:03.385662+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in
`wrapped_app'

2013-04-28T21:18:04.689716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-28T21:18:05.596424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-28T21:28:27.556270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2013-04-28T21:28:29.459229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 3598`

2013-04-28T21:18:03.385424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/con
figurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

2013-04-28T21:28:34.613321+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/con
figurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

I removed `resize.rb:23` file. It is for re-sizing images, app doesn't use, I just left it there on development and forgot to delete when uploaded my app on Heroku. On my local machine it is not run by itself, but Heroku for some reason started it. There was a function call to `C:\sbox\ruby\cards2` location and that's why the error happened, I thought. Ok, I removed the file. Do not know, though, about other issues.

But what do I need to do now? How to start the process again? I ran `git push heroku master` again but got:

```
C:\sbox\ruby\Sites\Heroku\Cards>git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
```

Nothing works but Heroku says that everything is up-to-date.

Is there a way to see all my app files on Heroku server the way you can see your files on shared hosting?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a commit with some small change, like a Readme change or something. It should force heroku to re-deploy your app.

Comment: Oh yes, this helped. Thank you. I have got a lot of errors about `Running: rake assets:precompile` but now I know how to go on.

Comment: I haven't tested this. But I'm assuming that a `git commit --allow-empty` would work, and then you don't need to make arbitrary changes to re-deploy.