# Deploy nodejs app heroku, error on git push

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

i am trying to deploy my application to Heroku, but, after have succesfully created the app, when i run in the shell the command

$ git push heroku master

the process doesn't start and after made me waiting some times it returns:

Initializing repositoryReceived disconnect from 50.19.85.132: 10: user closed connection
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

How can i solve this issue? I tried many ways but it seems i just can't deploy any app! Thank in advance

Comment: Do you have a heroku remote? What does git remote say? What about git remote show heroku?

Comment: i have an heroku remote, remote git says:
heroku git@heroku.com:tranquil-hollows-2002.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:tranquil-hollows-2002.git (push)
@diego.greyrobot

Comment: Try again later, there may be issues with the Heroku API right now: https://status.heroku.com/

Comment: god, did i really waste more than two ours for their bugs? uooofff. 

Do you really think this is the problem? @diego.greyrobot

Comment: You should try adding a commit message.
Similar problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268671/what-to-do-if-git-push-heroku-master-failed

Comment: i did it, this does not seem to be the problem.. @Ujjaval